# Переход с одной страницы сайта на другую через заданный промежуток времени

Tags: javascript, таймер

Очень нужен скрипт автоматического перехода с одной страницы сайта на другую страницу сайта, например, через 30 минут.

Comment: @RedStar, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

```
var delay = 1000; /* 1 миллисекунда*/

setTimeout(function(){ window.location = URL; }, delay);
```